# Disable cookie management spring boot 3 RestTemplateBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate, spring-boot-3

I am migrating from Spring Boot 2 -> Spring Boot 3

I had such method for getting the restTemplateBuilder to disable cookie management.

```
public static RestTemplateBuilder getRestTemplateBuilder() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
            HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .disableCookieManagement()
                .build()));
}
```

Now such method returns CloseableHttpClient instead

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().disableCookieManagement().build()
```

But the new `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(` expects `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: Hello springbooter99, I think your question is not complete as it ends in the mid of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was actually full sentence, but I added a "instead." to the end.